# Разделить всю страницу на несколько частей под углом

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать вот так с помощью css, html?

[image: ...]

Пытался сделать методом `:after` через `border`.

**P.S.** При том, что это будет целая страничка (`width 100%`, `height 100%`).

Comment: Можете в сторону `transform:skewX()` компнуть

Comment: Хорошая идея. Спасибо. Попробую конечно, но есть некоторые нюансы с левым вверху и правым внизу углом. Т.к. разворот блока не зальёт углы оставшиеся. Или я чего то не понимаю.

Comment: обертка с `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Как вариант https://stackoverflow.com/a/30052584/8255361 , но поддержка браузерами слабая

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 0 -4.5%;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
}

.item a {
  display: block;
  /* width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 10;
  
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}



.item a>span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) a{
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544891459-cf0d5d4b08e6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) a{
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544893215-e70de63912db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(3) a{
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544887786-5a1428e255e6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:nth-of-type(4) a{
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544883549-74fdf9e6ebc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Кликабельная ссылка #1</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Кликабельная ссылка #2</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Кликабельная ссылка #3</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Кликабельная ссылка #4</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```